# how to close shiro session

Tags: session, logout, shiro

I met an error when hardcode try to logout with shiro.
user do login and logout not through web login/logout url, but backend link.

when login, it works.

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(request.getParameter("username"), request.getParameter("password"));
        token.setRememberMe(true);
        try {
            currentUser.login(token);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but when i try to logout, with error:

```
public void userLogout(String sessionId){
    SecurityManager securityManager = SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager();
    Subject.Builder builder = new Subject.Builder(securityManager);
    builder.sessionId(sessionId);
    Subject subject = builder.buildSubject();
    if (null != subject) {
        try {
            subject.logout();
        } catch (SessionException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

but met error  [org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id , then how to manually colse a shiro session?

Comment: i fixed by user currentUser.logout, even don't know the root cause.

Comment: it's because if used above method to close current session, current thread can not be run over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't try to recreate the session and then operate it, you should get the session via the security manager, using the thread the user was logged into, like so:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
```

If you somehow want to call logout from a different thread, you can use the SessionDAO interface, but you need to do extra configuration to have shiro use a SessionDAO as described here:

http://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#SessionManagement-SessionStorage

When you have configured it correctly you can do stuff like:

```
    DefaultSecurityManager securityManager = (DefaultSecurityManager) SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager();
    DefaultSessionManager sessionManager = (DefaultSessionManager) securityManager.getSessionManager();
    Collection<Session> activeSessions = sessionManager.getSessionDAO().getActiveSessions();
    for (Session session: activeSessions){
        if (sessionId.equals(session.getId()){
            session.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, i noticed it and fix the issue. I should not try to close current thread via getSession(sessionId).logout. it causing session can not be found before current thread end. anyway, thanks.

Comment: this does not work for me. I use 'apache Shiro' with JSP servlet and Shiro is used with browser popup login.